# "standard" shebang with `-e`

Tags: bash, unix

So I used to start my bash scripts with `#!/bin/bash -e` (call bash, and exit on first error)

Now i'm moving to the more portable form  `#!/usr/bin/env bash` But setting `-e` doesn't work

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -e
echo 'hi'

# output:
>> /usr/bin/env: ‘bash -e’: No such file or directory
```

How can I use `-e` with the portable shebang?

Comment: `set -e` at the start of the script

Comment: That was _embarrassingly_ fast. Want to add it as an answer?

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` isn't more portable, but it does make it less likely your script will be executed with the version of `bash` you intended.

Comment: As an aside, although `set -e` mostly does what it says on the tin, you will likely find out that what it says on the tin is not what you want in error handling scenarios of any complexity.  Common shell constructs (such as statements in `if` clauses or used with `||` and `&&` logical operators) hide failures nested inside these constructs (i.e. occurring inside a function called directly or indirectly).  You should consider using traps, which do not have this awful drawback.

Comment: @fred thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [set](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html) command.

> **set** - Set or unset values of shell options and positional parameters.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

echo hi
```

Answer (score 5):

use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash -e
```

From the env manpage:

```
-S, --split-string=S
       process and split S into separate arguments; used to pass
       multiple arguments on shebang lines
```

Comment: What version of env is that?

Comment: Nvm looks like it was added in v8.30